# Why does masked animation look so strange?

Tags: unity, animation

I have an idle and a shooting animation.
Both animations are perfectly tailored to my model.

The idle animation looks like this:

[image]

And the shooting animation looks like this:

[image]

I have 2 animation layers:

The "Base" layer plays the idle animation.
The "Pistol Shooting" layers plays the pistol shooting animation, and it has an avatar mask because it should only influence the upper body.

The results however look like this:

[image]

[image]

What might be wrong here? What could I check?

Comment: The main thing that looks strange to me is that the legs are not in the right stance for shooting. Your shooting animation by itself has a stance where the upper body is leaned forward and the legs are positioned a specific way. When you mask it so only the upper body part is applied, the character now has this awkward leaning-forward pose that doesn't match the legs at all. The arms look a little different, but I'm not sure if that's the animation displaying incorrectly or just a different frame of the animation.

Comment: It appears to me like the result is actually a blend between the two animations. Can you show us your animation controller?

Comment: @Kevin I have checked. The hands are actually like this in the original animation, too.

Comment: @Philip Thank you. I think I found the problem. I had to exclude one bone. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I believe the solution was to exclude "abdomen".
As far as I could tell it now looks as expected.

[image]